# Why is my program crashing?

Tags: c, crash

I'm very new to C. I'm having a go at making a little something but I could not overcome this problem.

I deleted much from a copy of the program to narrow down the problem.
I'd like to know why it keeps crashing and tips are appreciated.
Thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char *name;
    printf("\nName your pet.\n");
    scanf("%s", name);

    int hunger = 5;
    int time = 0;
    int loop = 0;
    int day = 1;
    int happiness = 40;
    int health = 100;
    int tired = 0;
    int option;

    while(loop < 1){
    printf("\n\nDay %i\ntime = %i\n\n",day,time);
    printf("1 - check\n2 - interact\n3 - go out\n4 - inventory\n\n");
    scanf("\n%i",&option);
        if (option == 1) {
            if (tired >= 90){
                printf("\n %s is struggling to stay awake", name);
            }
            else if (tired >= 75){
                printf("\n %s looks really tired", name);
            }
            else if (tired >= 50){
                printf("\n %s is starting to seem a little sleepy", name);
            }
            else if ((tired <= 10)&&(hunger < 50)){
                printf("\n %s is full of energy", name);
            }




            time = time - 1;

        }




    time = time + 1;
    if (10<=time){
        day = day + 1;
        time = 0;
        tired = 0;
        printf("Goodnight!/n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't say where it is crashing, but did you initialize name?

Comment: Can you describe the specific error? Any idea where it is happening? Just posting the code is asking the community to debug it for you -won't be well received.

Comment: if you want to learn C, i recommend you also start learning gdb/valgrind and also look at http://c.learncodethehardway.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes at this line: `scanf("%s", name);`, because `name` is not initialized, so you cannot pass it to `scanf`.

Initialize `name` e.g. like this: `char *name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);`, so now a string with 20 characters fits in `name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't fully understand string variables yet, but that does the job!

Answer (score 0):

In your code,`name` is a `char*` which means that it is a pointer to `char`. Since you haven't allocated memory or given a valid address for the pointer,it points to some unknown location. Writing into this location is what triggered the crash.

To fix it, either change

```
char *name;
```

To

```
char name[100];
```

Or allocate memory dynamically using `malloc` as [suggested by @returntrue](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/27889151/why-is-my-program-crashing/27889195#27889195).